# MapBox direction with more than 25 waypoints in react

Tags: reactjs, mapbox

I am integrating MapBox Direction API in react. I have more than 25 waypoints (around 500). How do I use all using "mapbox-gl-directions". Because, I can't send not more than 25 wp. So, how can I send multiple request with 25 wp each time 25. How?

Below is my sample code:

````
componentDidMount() {
    let directions = new MapboxDirections({
                accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
                unit: 'metric',
                profile: 'mapbox/driving',
                interactive: false,
                controls: false
            });

    this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
            center: [3.1026, 36.6686],
            //center: [this.state.lng, this.state.lat],
            zoom: 10
        });

    this.map.on('load', function() {
        directions.setOrigin([-117.1425, 32.63638889]);
        directions.addWaypoint(0, [-117.1425, 32.63638889]);
        directions.addWaypoint(1, [-117.195, 32.75416667]);
        ---
        ---
        directions.addWaypoint(23, [-116.5012667, 32.92583333]);
        directions.setDestination([-116.5616667, 32.93583333]);
    })
    this.map.addControl(directions, 'top-left');
}```

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.
````

Answer (score 1):

You could break the waypoints up into 25 waypoints chunks and request directions from the [Directions API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/navigation/#directions) before loading the map. Then you could join the response route JSON objects to one route object, which you can then use in the same way as the single route object in terms of drawing it on the map.

Comment: Thanks Moritz, I have understood a bit what you have said and I think it would work. It would be more clear if you could given a sample example. So, could you please share a sample code if possible? 

Thanks again.